# Topology of Stochastic Matrices

Tags: general-topology, matrices, functional-analysis, probability-theory

Let $\mathcal{M} \subset \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ be the set of right stochastic matrices. Define a map, $T:\mathcal{M} \subset \mathbb{R}^{n \times m} \to \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ as $T(A)=A^TPA$ for a fixed matrix $P \in R^{n \times n}$ such that $0 \le p_{ij} \le 1, \sum \limits_{i,j}p_{ij}=1$.

I can easily see that $T$ is not linear, $\mathcal{M}$ is convex and closed and $T(\mathcal{M})$ is convex. But is it necessary that $T(\mathcal{M})$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$?

Thank you  in advance.

Content edited based on the comments given below.

Comment: It seems that you mean "Let $\mathcal{M} \subset \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ be *the* set of right stochastic matrices."?

Comment: Yes, thank you, I have edited it.

Comment: How is it that $T$ is linear? It's not linear as a function on $\mathbb R^{n\times m}$. Why is it linear on $\mathcal M$?

Comment: Oh yes, I am sorry, I overlooked it. You are right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\mathcal M$ is not only closed --- it's actually compact. And the continuous image of a compact set is compact.